# How to persist login state in react native voximplant SDK

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc, voximplant

I am developing a chat app and I have couple of screens:

1. Login/Register -> where I have created a nodejs server for authentication.
2. HomeScreen -> where all the conversations with people exists.
3. ChatScreen -> chats with a specific user. In here, I have given an option for video call/voice call, just like other apps out there.

Now the problem is with the **voximplant login functionality**. As I already have a backend which has an Authentication feature using jsonwebtoken, I don't want to login using the `voximplant` sdk too, but after several tries I had to because then only it will work. So, when I login/register using my nodejs API, I also login with `voximplant` SDK. Everything is cool till now, it works. But now if I kill the app and restarts it, as the `voximplant` login functionality was in the `login/register` component, (now it's not there because I am authenticated and in HomeScreen at this moment - using AsynStorage to store jsonwebtoken), so the `voximplant` SDK is logged out. Now there is no way in voximplant sdk (as far as I researched on their documentation) I could check that `if it is is logged out, log me in again`.

I could just login when I tap on video call icon (**although I cannot check whether I am logged out**), but that operation would be too expensive.

So is there anything I could do to make it work? Like, persist the state of voximplant when I already authenticated. Below are some relevant code snippets from my project.

Login/Register screen:

```js
import {Voximplant} from 'react-native-voximplant';

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const voximplant = Voximplant.getInstance();

  useEffect(() => {
    const connect = async () => {
      const status = await voximplant.getClientState();
      if (status === Voximplant.ClientState.DISCONNECTED) {
        await voximplant.connect();
      }
    };
    connect();
  }, []);

  const login = async (name) => {
    // voximplant login
    const fqUsername = `${name.toString()}@${APP_NAME}.${ACC_NAME}.voximplant.com`;
    const password = '....';
    await voximplant.login(fqUsername, password);

    // api login
    const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/login/`, {...})
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
         login(name);
       }}>
       <Text>Login</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Then after login, everything works as expected, but now when I close the app and kill it and launch it again, the feature doesn't work and throws `"NOT_LOGGED_IN"` in console.

I tried to `voximplant.connect` in HomeScreen but it was already connected, so the problem is, it does not persist the state.

HomeScreen.js:

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const voximplant = Voximplant.getInstance();

  useEffect(() => {
    const connect = async () => {
      const status = await voximplant.getClientState();
      if (status === Voximplant.ClientState.DISCONNECTED) {
        await voximplant.connect();
      }
    };
    connect();
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

CONSOLE output when I make a call:

```js
LOG Promise unhandled rejection id:0
"NOT_LOGGED_IN" // I couldn't find any event to check "NOT_LOGGED_IN" state.
```

So the question is: HOW TO STAY CONNECTED & MOST IMPORTANTLY - LOGGED IN.
Any help would be really appreciated!

DOCS: https://voximplant.com/docs/howtos/sdks/installing/react_native_sdk

Answer (score 1):

Voximplant SDK requires to establish the connection to the Voximplant Cloud and user authorization to make calls. It does not keep the login state between the application launches, as well as the connection state to the Voximplant Cloud.

Also, there may be the cases when the connection to the Voximplant Cloud is lost when the application is active (for example, network switch on a mobile device or poor internet connection). In these cases, the application should reconnect and relogin the user to make calls.

To handle these cases, the Voximplant React Native SDK provides the API:

1. to check the current [Client state](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/client#getclientstate)
2. to subscribe to connection state change [events](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/client#on)
3. login options (login with password, [login with access token](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/sdk/tokens) and [login with one time key](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/sdk/onetimekey))

For the case when the application is killed and launched again, I recommend one of the following solutions:

1. keep the connection to the Voximplant Cloud all application life, i.e
   if the client was previously logged with Voximplant SDK, connect to the Voximplant Cloud and login the user on the application launch using login with access token approach. If the connection to the Voximplant Cloud is lost for some reason, reconnect and relogin the client.
2. before making a call, check the client state and if it is not ["logged_in"](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/clientstate#logged_in), log in the client using access token. Connect and login operations are not too expensive and are preformed quickly.

Also, it is possible to move all connect/logic implementation to a separate functional component to avoid its duplication on different UI compoments such as login and home screen ([example](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-demo/blob/master/ConferenceDemo/src/Core/Services/AuthService.ts))

Comment: @chai86 you can contact us and ask any questions the following ways: 
1. email to our tech support: support@voximplant.com
2. join our developer community in discord: https://discord.gg/sfCbT5u

Answer (score -1):

It took me time also but ts like u caling your self or that user is not logined as online.
And try to reconect the app wen ever fails,disconect,connection,losts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).